# Sci fi novel, heatwave, time travellers, see through dress

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

A paperback novel I read mid 1970's UK.

Set in a USA town during a long heatwave, a lot of good looking strangers (who it is eventually revealed are from a few hundred years into the future) are moving in and taking up all the motel rooms and rented accommodation.

Male protagonist begins to take notice and starts a relationship with one of the people, he takes her for an expensive fancy meal but her reaction is "it's only food".

One evening he's in a club with her and as she walks across the room a section of her dress turns transparent and her breast is on show for a minute or so. All eyes are on her after that!

She explains it's a perfectly decent dress with a built in factor to randomly do this and she can't understand the fuss.

His suspicions grow about them being time travellers and he confronts her and discusses a  future where fertile land is in short supply, so a populace are conditioned to regard food and eating as just another exercise/chore. Also where fashion is very revealing.

She takes him to meet some of her party for updates of what will happen regarding the heatwave.

That's all I got, I can't remember if they turned out to be benign or bad.

Comment: @user14111 nope, sorry, I've tried but the cover doesn't come back to me

Comment: No, I really can't remember, maybe the heatwave causes a disaster? (Guessing only, just can't remember) it was a typical size paperback of those days, a lot shorter than modern ones)

Comment: The randomly revealing costume and future worse than the present reminds me of some of Spider Robinson's plots (c.f. "The Free Lunch"), but none I can recall match this well.

Comment: The randomly disappearing costume shows up at the beginning of *Sentenced to Prism* as an advertising scheme (the ads were the default, the periodic nudity to get people to watch), but otherwise, it doesn't match.

Comment: do you remember anything about the cover? Placement of the words/color/images?

Comment: No, really can't I'm afraid. There MIGHT have been a blend of heroic men and stunning women on the cover but I can't be certain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Vintage Season](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59665)* by Lawrence O'Donnell (pseudonym for
C. L. Moore and Henry Kuttner), and can be found here
[Astounding, Sept. 1946](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v38n01_1946-09_cape1736).

As you recall, there was a disaster involved, and the mysterious guests
made reference to their tourism in other times.

Comment: I've accepted this with some reservations, it's possible I got two books confused and was thinking of 'A Vintage Season' all along.